# Idiom or slang to show you're scared and/or sorry

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang, idiom-requests

Is there any idiom, phrase or slang you use when you have done something wrong and you want to show you are really sorry?

Whether you are deeply sorry or you're just saying that because you are scared? Something that means "I'm really sorry and it won't happen again".
For example:

> A: Not again! You used my car?!!! I'm gonna kill you!
>   B: (scared) So
>   sorry! It's not gonna happen again.

Something to use in B

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would want to say, "I'm scared and really sorry." On hearing that people might think that I'm not really sorry, and I'm  saying I am only because I'm scared and want to placate the person I've offended. But if I just say, "I'm really sorry" and look very much not scared, I have a better chace my expression of sorrow will be seen as genuine.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, no, there's no common expression that you would use yourself.

Most people would add emphasis with modifiers like, "I'm *so* sorry," "I'm *really* sorry," "I'm *terribly* sorry," "I'm *truly* sorry."

Other people might get poetic with something like, "my heart is at the bottom of the ocean over this." But if you go there, you're making up a new one. It's not an idiom, it's new poetry.

Perhaps someone else has one I'm not thinking of. :)

Answer (score 1):

> A: Not again! You used my car?!!!
>   B: (scared) So sorry! It's not gonna happen again [something to put here]

Something "to put here" might be *Honestly!*

However, putting anything there might be seen as over-egging the pudding, being **too** apologetic. If one is too apologetic, it has exactly the opposite effect because it may be seen as sarcastic — it may be construed as meaning that one is not sorry at all, and/or that the car will be used again. That might not be the case if it's accompanied by obvious cowering and distress.

Comment: What if you're more scared than sorry?

Comment: @Cheiloproclitic, not necessarily idiomatic, but you can offer to kill yourself (then not do it): "I'll kill myself. It's not gonna happen again then, for sure."

Answer (score 1):

One might say ***"Man, I really stepped in it!"*** or ***"Boy, I really screwed the pooch there!"***, followed by an apology.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an issue of word choice. I think it's an issue of eye contact, sincerity in delivery, and body language.  Sometimes the words can only say so much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I could have sworn I had a better answer for this. **Sorry, my mistake!** ... I'll see myself out. If you'd just, "[Gimme three steps](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gimme%20three%20steps&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)."

Answer (score 1):

These are the words usable, depending on the situation

1. Humbled
2. Humiliated
3. Regretful
4. Remorseful
5. Rueful
6. Contrite
7. Repentant

Let's say a boy had felt the freedom to accuse another party of being in the wrong. Then, the situation turns out that the other party was right and the boy was the wrong. He would feel humbled or humiliated to not make such an accusation again. There would be possibility he is not really penitent, but by peer pressure of embarrassment.

One could be compelled towards regret, motivated not by sincerity, but by the current situation or by impending punishment or embarrassment.

1. Reluctant, reluctantly
2. With reluctant remorse
3. With reserved contrition
4. Excessive penitence
5. Aggrieved
6. Ruefully aggrieved

You would feel ruefully aggrieved, when you wish you hadn't done something which you did, and when you are caught doing it, but yet you believe there is nothing wrong doing it, and now you are in dread of the unjustified consequences.

---

[rue•ful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rueful) (ˈru fəl)

adj.

1. feeling, showing, or expressing sorrow or regret: a rueful admission.
2. causing sorrow or pity; pitiable; deplorable.

rue′ful•ly, adv.
rue′ful•ness, n.

*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

---

[con•trite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrite) (kənˈtraɪt, ˈkɒn traɪt)

adj.

1. caused by or showing sincere remorse.
2. filled with a sense of guilt and the desire for atonement; penitent: a contrite sinner.

[Middle English contrit (< Anglo-French) < Latin contrītus worn down, crushed, past participle of conterere. See con-, trite]

con•trite′ly, adv.
con•trite′ness, n.

*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

---

[con•trite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrite)
adjective - sorry, humble, chastened, sorrowful, repentant, remorseful, regretful, penitent, conscience-stricken, in sackcloth and ashes He was so contrite that he wrote me a letter of apology.

*Collins Thesaurus of the English Language – Complete and Unabridged 2nd Edition. 2002 © HarperCollins Publishers 1995, 2002*

---

[ag•grieved](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aggrieved) (əˈgrivd)

adj.

1. wronged or injured.
2. Law. deprived of legal rights or claims.
3. troubled; worried.

*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*